# All keys from hash with matching array values in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash, hashmap

I have a hash such as:

```
CHAR_MAP = {
  :x => %w[something]
  :y => %w[something2 something]
  :z => %w[something3 something1]
  :r => %w[something something3]
  ...
  ...
}
```

And I have another array

```
x = ['something', 'something3']
```

Now for the hash `CHAR_MAP` I want a list of keys for which all the values in it's corresponding `value array` are a part of the array `x`

So for `array x` we should get the keys `x` and `r` as output

```
@recommendation_factors.each do |rf|
  @rec_list = CHAR_MAP.detect{|h| h == rf.recommendation_factor}
end
```

I tried the above but it keeps on returning an empty array. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
CHAR_MAP.keys.select { |k| (CHAR_MAP[k] - x).empty? }
```